# How do I take it as a parameter in JIT?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am using tailwindcss with JIT.

I am creating a custom utility.
I made it without parameters.

I would like to make it accept JIT parameters.
(I don't know if that's the right term)

code:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  @variants responsive {
    .under-line:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 80%; /* <---- How do I take it as a parameter? */
      border-top: none;
      border-left: none;
      border-right: none;
      border-bottom: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
  }
}
```

usage scenarios:

```
<div class="under-line-[80%]">foo</div>
```

How do I take it as a parameter?

Comment: Maybe try this plugin: https://github.com/mertasan/tailwindcss-variables

Answer (score 1):

The below solution is valid only if we assume that you want to pass only percent values.

Maybe it's not a direct answer, but I think that it'll help you in this case.

You can define a custom plugin in TailwindCSS. With that knowledge, you can generate with tailwind config 100 variants of this class like `.under-line-x`, where `x` is a number from range 1-100 and is set to `:after` element `width` property as percent.

The beginning of your tailwind config should look like that:

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addComponents }) {

      let components = {};

      for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        components[`.under-line-${i}:after`] = {
          content: '""',
          display: 'block',
          width: i + '%',
          border: 'none',
          borderBottom: 'solid',
          borderColor: 'black',
          borderWidth: '1px'
        }
      }

      addComponents(components)

    })
  ],
  // rest of your config
}
```

Overall, JIT will remove unused variants.

Comment: upvote: it's not a direct answer, but it's a good idea.