# Is there a shorter way to write a border on only one side?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I got borders on all the edges by doing something like:

It is actually a mistake, but at the time of the question I believe I can draw a line only to the TOP with the following code. (Actually, lines are drawn on all edges.)

```
<div class="border border-blue-900 border-t-1">foo</div>
```

I wanted to display it only on one side, so I did some research.
I noticed that when I used `border` in `tailwindcss`,
the following was output in the output file.

> /**
>
> - 1. Prevent padding and border from affecting element width.
> - 
> - We used to set this in the html element and inherit from
> - the parent element for everything else. This caused issues
> - in shadow-dom-enhanced elements like  where the content
> - is wrapped by a div with box-sizing set to `content-box`.
> - 
> - https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/4
> - 
> - 
> - 2. Allow adding a border to an element by just adding a border-width.
> - 
> - By default, the way the browser specifies that an element should have no
> - border is by setting it's border-style to `none` in the user-agent
> - stylesheet.
> - 
> - In order to easily add borders to elements by just setting the `border-width`
> - property, we change the default border-style for all elements to `solid`, and
> - use border-width to hide them instead. This way our `border` utilities only
> - need to set the `border-width` property instead of the entire `border`
> - shorthand, making our border utilities much more straightforward to compose.
> - 
> - https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/pull/116
>   */

The original of this output would have come from
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/723e8d4377eb25b66a6224f767937fa02762eb52/src/plugins/css/preflight.css#L71

I thought this was probably the cause.
I have succeeded in applying it only to the top edge by writing the following.

```
<div class="border border-blue-900 border-t-1 border-l-0 border-r-0 border-b-0">foo</div>
```

However, this is too long. Is there any way to make it shorter?

**Note:** I am also considering the following as alternatives.

[How do I take it as a parameter in JIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68877759/how-do-i-take-it-as-a-parameter-in-jit)

This way, I can also adjust the width (not the width in the border, it is for `display: block`).

What I want to do is just display it on any one side, so the above link is trying to display it on the bottom. (In other words, it doesn't matter if it's at the top, bottom, or anywhere else. It's just an example.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can apply border-width of 2px only to the top edge according to the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-width) as following

```
<div class="border-t-2 border-blue-900">foo</div>
```

The error made was there is no utility class called `border-t-1` in tailwind-CSS. Also applying `border` utility class adds the the CSS styling of `border-width: 1px;` which adds a border-width to all sides.

Check out the solution at [tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/uBB7kVb2zB)

**EDIT:** Check out [shingo.nakanishi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68878038/13833218) top apply `border-top-width` of `1px` if you are using [JIT](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#enabling-jit-mode) mode

Comment: Here it sets a `2px` border. If want `1px` border `border-0 border-t` works just fine

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna Yes. And I have mentioned it above, This was answered for tailwind version 2.

Comment: im not sure if this works if preflight is disabled

Answer (score 17):

You can achieve this by using below class

```
border-solid border-0 border-t border-blue-900
```

Comment: this one works when preflight is disabled

Answer (score 14):

Thanks [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68877990/1979953).
I use JIT, I can make the following for 1px:

```
<div class="border-t-[1px] border-blue-900">foo</div>
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is the same as just `border-t`

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR; for no preflight: `border-[0] border-t border-solid border-black`

---

For those who do not have `preflight` from Tailwind (which is their css reset rules), the default browser `border-width` is `1px`, so when setting `border-solid` all border will be shown.

A `1px` top border can then be added with `border-[0]  border-t border-solid border-black`, where `border-[0]` will first reset the `border-width`, and `border-t` is `border-width-top: 1px;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but sometimes I need to add `border-b-0 border-r-0 border-l-0` in addition to the provided answers ( That worked for me, but not always ). If someone knows why, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is pulling their hair out as to why something like `border-t border-t-sky-500` isn’t working, and you’re using Tailwind through PostCSS, then check your PostCSS invocation.

If you omit the `-o {outfile}` and use the stdout output feature, Tailwind prints debug output so you end up with something like this at the beginning of your final production CSS:

```
Source path:foo/bar/baz.css Setting up new context... Finding changed files:123.456ms Reading changed files:123.456ms Generate rules:123.456ms Build stylesheet:123.456ms Potential classes:123 Active contexts:123 JIT TOTAL:967.483ms *, ::before, ::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#e5e7eb
}
```

In other words, using `stdout` output of PostCSS with Tailwind ruins the first style rule of Tailwind, which includes setting `border-style: solid` on everything.

This is a bug, and it must be filed somewhere, but I couldn’t find it so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you came here because you can only get borders with defining `border-style`, it might be because of not using `@tailwind base` in your global CSS (or it might not be loaded correctly). Because these styles are defined for borders in tailwind base:

```css
* {
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: currentColor;
}
```